# How to break live video into quadrants (Optic Flow + Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

**The short summary:**
Need to run a function on a quadrant of streaming video independently, but not the entire frame. How do I break live video into quadrants to analyze each quadrant independently? (python + optic flow)

Hello,
I think optic flow is really cool and so I wanted to try something like that using my hamsters as a model.

I have an aerial view of my hamster cage, where the top third is the bedding, middle third is the wheel, and the bottom third is the water/food.

**Can I use optic flow to obtain statistical data that could tell me which third of my hamster cage has the most movement?**

In order to do that, would I need to manually break up my video into three separate files, each consisting of a third of the video? OR is there a way to select quadrants, possibly by selecting coordinates to form a rectangle?

I found this code using this tutorial: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

```
# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))
```

But I can't seem to find details (particularly on "**winSize** or "**maxCorners**" on how to select for specific coordinates to set my quadrants.

Unless... I completely missed it in the documentation or in another tutorial. I would appreciate any help. What else can I do with optic flow? Any other fun research ideas using optic flow I could play around with for the summer?

Comment: To see which quadrant has the most movement, all you need to do is compute the variance in the time signal. More movement = more variance. Load your video as a 3D (x,y,t) array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you- do you have any supporting literature on that? I can't seem to find something on "variance of time signal" on Google

Comment: I mean to compute the variance of a pixel over time. In your 3D array, compute variance along the *t* axis, then average per quadrant. If the scene is static, pixels will not change color over time, and the variance will be 0 (or close, there's always noise).